# Reading from a textfile with different columns into an array C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to read the following text file into an array as is. The issue is in the `readData` function other code is provided for context.

the `movies.txt` file

```
The next 2 lines are to show the whitespace count, they are not part of the data.
000000000111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888889999
123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123
Jan 25, 1970       MASH                                         $3,025,000        $81,600,000
Aug 5, 1983        The Star Chamber                             $8,000,000         $5,555,305
Oct 2, 1977        Julia                                        $7,840,000        $20,714,400
May 25, 1979       Alien                                       $11,000,000       $104,931,801
June 3, 1988       Big                                         $18,000,000       $151,668,774
Dec 25, 1992       Hoffa                                       $35,000,000        $29,302,121
Nov 1, 1996        Romeo + Juliet                              $14,500,000       $147,554,999
April 9, 1999      Never Been Kissed                           $25,000,000        $84,565,230
Dec 15, 1974       Young Frankenstein                           $2,780,000        $86,273,333
Dec 27, 1991       Naked Lunch                                 $18,000,000         $2,641,357
May 17, 1974       Dirty Mary Crazy Larry                       $1,140,000        $28,401,735
March 2, 1979      Norma Rae                                    $4,500,000        $22,228,000
Nov 26, 1997       Alien Resurrection                          $75,000,000       $161,295,658
Sept 23, 1970      Tora! Tora! Tora!                           $25,485,000        $29,548,291
June 21, 1991      Dying Young                                 $26,000,000        $82,264,675
June 15, 1979      Butch and Sundance: The Early Days           $9,000,000         $2,260,000
```

Read each row of each column into an array

=> My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct Movie {
    string releaseDate;
    string movieName;
    double prodCost;
    double grossProfit;
};


void readData(ifstream& in, Movie movie[], int count)
{
    string releaseDate;
    string movieName;
    double prodCost;
    double grossProfit;

    in.open("movies.txt");
// this needs to read each column in a row to an array of structs
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        in >> releaseDate >> movieName >> prodCost >> grossProfit;
        movie[i].releaseDate = releaseDate;
        movie[i].movieName = movieName;
        movie[i].prodCost = prodCost;
        movie[i].grossProfit = grossProfit;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size = 0;
    string dateOfRelease;
    string movieName;
    double productionCost;
    double grossProfit;

    ifstream input;

    input.open("movies.txt");

    while (input >> dateOfRelease >> movieName >> productionCost >> grossProfit) {
        size++;
    }

    input.close();
    Movie* movie = new Movie[size];
    readData(input, movie, size);
}
```

Comment: How are the fields separated?

Comment: You probably need to read a line at a time into a std::string.

Comment: @NeilButterworth the field are seperated by white spaces

Comment: If they are not separated by _specific_ white-space character, such as tabs, you can't read it directly with the facilities of the iostream library. You could write a parser for it, or you could chop out fixed-sized records. Also, if you keep on editing the question, it's hard to help.

Comment: @comphonia The fields are separated by whitespace, but they also have whitespace inside them. The dates and the titles contain spaces. That's what make this hard and why your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My observations about this particular file format are:

- each line is exactly 93 characters long
- the title starts in column 20
- the production cost ends in column 74; the data consists of digits, commas and a single $ to the very left
- the gross profit is formatted like the production cost

To split a line into fields, I would use this strategy:

- ensure that the line has exactly 93 characters, otherwise error out
- characters 01 until 20 form the date; it needs to be trimmed from whitespace; luckily you don't need to parse the date further into year, month, day
- to get the title, start in column 74; as long as there are digits or commas, go left; after that, the current character must be a dollar, otherwise error out; go left again; you are now at the right edge of the title
- the title starts in column 20; take the substring(20, title_end) and trim it
- parse substring(title_end + 1, 74) as a monetary amount
- trim substring(75, 93) and parse it as a monetary amount

To parse a string as a monetary amount:

- remove the leading '$'
- starting from the back, check each 4th character if it is a comma; if so, remove it
- parse the remaining string as a double

This whole task sounds quite complicated. This is because the file format is not a standard file format that has built-in delimiters, such as XML, JSON, CSV. Therefore parsing it needs a lot of custom code.

When parsing this file format, watch out for ambiguous titles like "The $1,000,000 man" or very long titles that might reach up into column 67. Your example does not contain these extreme examples, but that in itself doesn't mean that such examples could not exist.

Comment: Hey, thanks, the pseudocode / proposed algorithm is perfect, parsing this will definitely take some time since all the values will need to be parsed again after sorting to add the $ and commas. I will see if the points for this will be worth my time. Thank you.